# remove lines with first column with 6 digits in a csv files

Tags: python, csv, sed, awk, grep

I got a csv file like this

```
"5478",a,56.40,-0.40 ,55.50,57.50,55.30,56.74,"862,971","48,962,460","695",56.40,56.60,"127,474,332",56.40,60.30,52.50
"5480",b,21.90,-0.25 ,21.80,22.00,21.80,21.87,"1,598,041","34,950,597","590",21.90,21.95,"199,097,830",21.90,23.40,20.40
"70462P",c,0.01,-0.01 ,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,"99,000","990","1",0.01,0.06,"5,000,000",0.01,0.31,0.01
"70465P",d, ---,--- ,---,---,---,0.02,"0","0","0",0.01,0.03,"20,000,000",0.02,0.32,0.01
"8935",bt,5.02,-0.02 ,4.95,5.19,4.92,5.05,"949,102","4,791,070","290",5.02,5.07,"201,902,107",5.02,5.37,4.67
1333,tnd,21.40,-0.60 ,22.00,22.20,21.20,21.52,"1,519,292","32,692,804","631",21.40,21.50,"102,525,625",21.40,22.85,19.95
```

I'd like to check the first column, if it is over 4 digits, then remove the line, so for example, the 2nd and the 3rd row will be removed.
How do I do this? thanks a lot

ps2
This is stock information downloaded from stock center, but I found the format is changed recently, the format before is as the last line, the first column is without quotation "", is it possible to filter the two formats? or I should deal with the 2 cases?

Comment: I don't have any idea, I guess awk + sed will do great

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a `sed` solution:

```
sed -e '/^"[0-9]\{5\}/d' in-file > out-file
```

You can also do an in-place replacement using the [`-i` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed):

```
sed -i -e '/^"[0-9]\{5\}/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what language u'd like, because u marked awk and sed in tags, but You could simply use grep:

```
egrep '^\"[0-9]{1,4}\"' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

#### awk

```
awk -F, '$1~ /^\"[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?\"$/' file
```

#### GNU sed

```
sed '/^\"[0-9]\{1,4\}\"/!d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv, tempfile, shutil

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as fin, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as fout:
    w = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        if len(row[0]) <= 4:
            w.writerow(row)

shutil.move(fout.name, 'data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. I am assuming `lines` is a iterator each loop giving one line from the CSV file.

```
for line in lines:
    if len(line.split(',')[0]) <= 4: #consider this line
        print line #process this line
    else:
        pass
```